# How to apply filter in Azure table client

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-table-storage

I am working on Azure storage table. Below is the partitionKey and rowkey

1. partitionKey  = Product Type
2. rowKey = Region

I have used below filter to get the data (see the code below). **If rowkey (region) is null then it should get product Type from all region.** However, It get empty data. If I pass valid Partitionkey(ProductType) and RowKey (region) it's get the data.

```
AsyncPageable<T> result =TableClient.QueryAsync<T>(filter: $"PartitionKey eq '{partitionKey}' and RowKey eq '{rowKey}'");
```

**Note: Partition-key is mandatory**

Any advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If rowkey (region) is null then it should get product Type from all
> region.

If this is what you want, you would need to change the code to something like following:

```cs
AsyncPageable<T> result = TableClient.QueryAsync<T>(filter: $"PartitionKey eq '{partitionKey}'");
```

**UPDATE**

> What I would like is If user has provided ProductType and Region then
> filter using both. In case user only provide ProductType then include
> all regions.

In this case, you will need to use two different queries - one when both PartitionKey and RowKey are present and other when only PartitionKey is present.

Your code would be something like:

```cs
var query = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rowKey) ? 
  $"PartitionKey eq '{partitionKey}'" : $"PartitionKey eq '{partitionKey}' and RowKey eq '{rowKey}'";
AsyncPageable<T> result = TableClient.QueryAsync<T>(filter: query);
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, What if I want data base on ProductType and Region( For example - Asia region)

What I would like is If user has provided ProductType and Region then filter using both. In case user only provide ProductType then include all regions.